# XML/SQL - Adding a string at the end of each line in individual fields

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xslt, newline

In Postgres I am trying to append a string to the end of each line of data in an individual field.

For example, I have the following database table called **personal_details**:

```
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  name |   age  |                       details                       |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Dave  |   67   |  This is some text made by Dave                     |  <-- Note the next sentence is on the next line
|       |        |  He is a dentist and works five days a week         |
|       |        |                                                     |  <-- Note there is a blank line between these two sentences 
|       |        |  He enjoys sports and loves burgers                 |
|       |        |  He hates pizza                                     |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Paul  |   34   |  This is some text from a different person          |
|       |        |                                                     | 
|       |        |  Paul is always very happy                          |
|       |        |  He loves dogs                                      | 
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Lucy  |   27   |  Lucy is the only girl in this database table       |
|       |        |  She likes coffee                                   |
|       |        |                                                     |
|       |        |  She does karate at the weekend                     |
+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**The problem (greatly simplified for the purposes of explaining my question):**

I am using the `personal_details` table to create a View called `personal_details_view` with the following simple SQL:

```
SELECT personal_details.name, personal_details.age, peronsal_details.details 
FROM personal_details
```

However in this View, in the `Details` field of the table above I want to insert a particular string at the end of each sentence depending on whether there is a single newline or a double new line.

**For example in the View the `Detail` fields for Dave, Paul and Lucy would become:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
This is some text made by Dave</text></line><line><text>                                               <-- to signify a SINGLE newline followed this
He is a dentist and works five days a week</text></line><line><text></text></line><line><text>         <-- to signify a DOUBLE newline followed this
He enjoys sports and loves burgers</text></line><line><text>
He hates pizza
--------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------
This is some text from a different person</text></line><line><text></text></line><line><text>          <-- to signify a DOUBLE newline followed this
Paul is always very happy</text></line><line><text>                                                    <-- to signify a SINGLE newline followed this 
He loves dogs
---------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------
Lucy is the only girl in this database table</text></line><line><text>                                 <-- to signify a SINGLE newline followed this 
She likes coffee</text></line><line><text></text></line><line><text>                                   <-- to signify a DOUBLE newline followed this
She does karate at the weekend
---------------------------------------------------------
```

**`</text></line><line><text>`** signifying a single new line followed this sentence

**`</text></line><line><text></text></line><line><text>`** signifying a double new line followed this sentence.

I may be overlooking an obvious way this can be done, but I cannot see a logical way of doing this.

Comment: Why not add the newlines directly in the field?

Comment: in this case, postgres function replace or regexp_replace can do the job for you.

Comment: @foibs - I've edited my question to better explain why. It is because this data is then used in a transform to correctly space lines in a text file, plus I need this to be done automatically rather than to manually change every single one. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, there is no real distinguishing between one newline or two newlines

Does this do the job?

```
select replace(details, E'\n', '</text></line><line><text>'||E'\n') from personal_details
```

EDIT:
After reading your latest edit with extra care to the desired result,
I also suggest a double replace:

```
select replace(
  replace(details, E'\n\n', '</text></line><line><text>'||E'\n'),
E'\n', '</text></line><line><text>'||E'\n')
from personal_details
```

The inner replace which runs first, replaces all double newline chars with your desired extra string just once, plus one newline,

while the outer replace further adds the desired string in all newlines encountered.

If you want single line output in your file, you can just remove the last `||E'\n'` of the outer replace